# How to save changes on the registry outside of the container in Windows Docker?

Tags: docker, windows-container

I am currently investigating a bit in Docker and know that you can map files and folders of the host-system to the container so that after the container got killed, the files are still available (Volumes).

So I asked myself, how about changes in the Windows registry? Lets assume that an app also does some modifications there, which I want to keep. How do I do that?

Comment: Define a volume for the path where the registry is stored?

Comment: thats a good suggestion ;) but in that case I can only save the complete HKLM, HKCU, etc. ? right

Comment: Why do you need to do that? If you need changes to registry persisted, just make those changes in dockerfile. Registry even though is stored on file system can not be moved around. `Docker commit` is not working in Windows either.

Comment: I actually don’t need it. I was just thinking about the case when I have an application that creates application data as well as changes registry data, like a link to the created files. I know, it sounds stupid and probably an application like this does not exist but I was just curious :)